# Call a javascript function on each ajax request

Tags: jquery, ajax, asp.net-mvc-4

Do we have any way to call a javascript function on each ajax request to server in MVC 4.

Comment: Have you even tried anything?

Comment: Yes, there is a way to do this.  Show us what you've tried and we'll help you with it :)

Comment: yes I tried and found a best solution.   $("body").bind("ajaxSend", function (e, xhr, settings) {
                            alert("Sent");
                        }).bind("ajaxComplete", function (e, xhr, settings) {
                            alert("Complete");
                        }).bind("ajaxError", function (e, xhr, settings, thrownError) {
                            alert("Error");
                        });    This is the script that best suited in my mvc application that gets called on each ajax sent, complete and error occurences.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[SEE (and please read) DOC](http://api.jquery.com/ajaxSend/)

```
$( document ).ajaxSend(myFunction);
```

Comment: This script worked fine in my code. $("body").bind("ajaxSend", function (e, xhr, settings) { alert("Sent"); }).bind("ajaxComplete", function (e, xhr, settings) { alert("Complete"); }).bind("ajaxError", function (e, xhr, settings, thrownError) { alert("Error"); }); This is the script that best suited in my mvc application that gets called on each ajax sent, complete and error occurences. Thanks A. Wolff for your support.